# smart cast option for a specific champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

I usually tend to put smartcast on my w key for escapes on my champions which are corki,tristana and zed.But lately ive been trying out new champions,one of which is kayle and it feels uncromfortable and wierd in my opinion when i try to heal myself or an ally with my w on smartcast.

Is there an option i can use on the lol client to allow me to put smartcast key on any individual champion or does smartcast have to affect all the champions i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third-party program to achieve this. [Enigma's Smartcast Manager](http://enigmablade.net/lol-smartcast-manager/) is notable for allowing you to have a separate smartcast configuration for each champion. (Riot has no issue with you using programs like this.)

Comment: k,thnxxxxxxxx :)